# Настроить скролл элемента из map

Tags: reactjs

я получаю массив объектов и отрендериваю их при помощи map

```
{item.regions.map((item) => (
        <Box>
            <Typography
                color={selectedChip === item.region_name ? 'green' : theme.palette?.text?.disabled}
                typography='overline'
                sx={{ ml: 2 }}
            >
                {item.region_name.toUpperCase()}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
                ref={targetRef}
                typography='sequence'
                sx={{
                    borderTop: `1px solid ${
                        selectedChip === item.region_name ? 'green' : theme.palette?.text?.disabled
                    }`,
                    letterSpacing: '4px',
                    fontSize: '14px',
                    display: 'flex',
                    ml: 2,
                    pb: 1,
                    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                }}
            >
                {item.sequence}
            </Typography>
        </Box>
    ))}
```

В первом Typography я прописываю название объекта
Во-втором sequence это некоторая последовательность - просто строка.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на имя, горизонтальный скролл передвигался к нужной последовательности (последовательности намного длинее), так вот я знаю как сделать скролл, но не знаю как мне повесить реф на нужнный мне элемент из map-а, то есть в item.regions у меня 100 объектов, у каждого есть свой name и sequence, если я нажимаю на name4, то скролл должен переходить на sequnce4, для этого нужно использовать scrollToView() - и здесь нужно указать конкретный Typography, как через getElementById, только я не знаю как это сделать при помощи рефов, буду рад любой помощи!